# How to export blender material as .material file and GLSL on Blender 2.8

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders

I've seen alot of tutorials that explain how to save material and import it via append file but i wanted to export the material node as .material file and if possible, convert it into GLSL shader codes on blender 2.8?